# Subquery on outer query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

UPDATE: Please look at the second query, it is more representable for this example

I'd like to create a query that uses different subqueries for each column.
The subqueries would be based on the list obtained by the outer query.

For example:
Consider tableA is a table with 30 columns and 5 million records

```
SELECT a, b, c,
(SELECT COUNT(a) FROM values WHERE (r = 12 AND u = 'TO') OR (r = 16 AND u IN ('TB', 'TU')) as First,
(SELECT COUNT(a) FROM values WHERE (r = 16 AND u = 'TE') OR (r = 76 AND u IN ('TE', 'TG')) as Second,
(SELECT COUNT(a) FROM values WHERE (r = 564 AND u = 'HG') OR (r = 788 AND u IN ('VD', 'BF')) as Third,
(SELECT COUNT(a) FROM values WHERE (r = 383 AND u = 'RT') OR (r = 35 AND u IN ('GR', 'EZ')) as Fourth
FROM tableA values
```

I know this query would not execute since I can't call values from the subqueries, but is there a good solution to make this query run fast?

---

In some subqueries, I'd also need to join to another table, is it then still possible to use values, or do I have to do a subquery on tableA again?

---

Following query would be more representable for this example:

```
SELECT col1, col2,

(SELECT COUNT(col3) FROM tableA ta
INNER JOIN tableB b ON tl.TaskId = b.col6
INNER JOIN tableC c ON b.Id = c.TaskId
WHERE c.ResultCode = 1 AND ta.col4 = a.col4 AND ta.col5 = a.col5) as Executed,

(SELECT COUNT(col3) FROM tableA ta
INNER JOIN tableB b ON tl.TaskId = b.col6
INNER JOIN tableC c ON b.Id = c.TaskId
WHERE c.ResultCode = 9 AND ta.col4 = a.col4 AND ta.col5 = a.col5) as NotExecuted

FROM tableA a
GROUP BY col1, col2, col4, col5
```

Comment: So you want those columns populated for only 4 specific values of `b` and NULL otherwise?  Can you give an example of what you want the result set to look like?

Comment: The query I am working on will have more complicated WHERE clauses, but I am just using the values of b as example. I just want the count so it will either be 0 or an amount.
Considering the WHERE clause will be more complicated, the example I have given isn't representable, I will correct it immediately.

Comment: Soo, this would output the same four counts, 5 million times. Not the best way to gather this data mayhaps :)

Comment: Indeed, I will recreate my example query to a more representable query.

Comment: I have added a second query which will be more representable for this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a, b, c,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL AND b=12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as First,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL AND b=16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Second, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL AND b=82 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Third,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL AND b=167 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Fourth
    FROM tableA        
    GROUP BY a, b, c
```

Comment: wouldn't this just output 1 or 0 for each row (per those 4 columns)?

Comment: @Mackan: No, because of the SUM.

Comment: Yeh I see the sum, but I also see "SELECT a, b, c" before the SUMs. Now that you added GROUP BY it makes more sense ;)

Comment: I have added a second query which will be more representable for this example.